# Substitute for @additionalLabels in Neo4j GraphQL 2.0

Tags: neo4j, graphql, grandstack

We run a project that uses the @additionalLabels directive to create multi-tenancy like it is suggested by the older version of the GRANDstack documentation.

Now we run into the problem when migration to the new version that this directive is "Not supported at this time" as it is stated here https://neo4j.com/docs/graphql-manual/current/guides/migration-guide/type-definitions/#_additionallabels

Does anyone know

1. a workaround to get it done as elegant as in the former version
2. when this directive will be available again

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no workaround for this at this time(20/09/2021), however, we merged [this](https://github.com/neo4j/graphql/pull/475) pull request a few days ago, that includes your desired functionally. It will be released very soon.

Comment: Thanks for the swift response! To my question here and to the need for this directive by the community. You all do a great job with that library. Many Thanks!